# How to asynchronously call a shell script from Python?

Tags: python, subprocess, python-3.7, python-multithreading, python-3.8

I have a shell script which does some processing over the string passed and then writes it to a file. However I don't want my function foo() to wait for it to complete the operation. How do I call `process(msg)` and then move on the with the execution of `{code block 2}` without waiting for `process(msg)` to complete execution?

```
def process(msg):
    subprocess.call(['sh', './process.sh', msg])

def foo():
    # {code block 1}
    process(msg)
    # {code block 2}
```

`foo()` will be called from another function, almost once or twice per second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

subprocess.call() and subprocess.run() creates a process, waits for it to finish, and returns a CompletedProcess object.

subprocess.Popen() creates a process and returns it. It is used under the hood of the previous functions. You can then wait for the process to finish, send it messages, or whatever else you want to do with it. The arguments are mostly the same as to `call` or `run`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

As a bit of elaboration, Popen is the python implementation of using the os to start a new process. os.fork() is a lower level that doesn't actually do what we want here, that would spawn another instance of the python interpreter with the same memory state as the current one. If you wanted to use the lower level syscall, `os.spawn` is closer to `subprocess.run` than `os.fork`.

To verify that Popen is doing what you want, this test program will pring "returncode = None", then wait 5 seconds, and print "returncode = 0"

```
from subprocess import Popen

p = Popen(["sleep", "5"])
print("started the proc")  # this will print immediately
p.poll()  # this checks if the process is done but does not block
print(f"p returncode = {p.returncode}")
p.wait()  # this blocks until the process exits
print(f"p returncode = {p.returncode}")
```

Comment: so if I understand it right, if I use `subprocess.popen(['sh', './process.sh', msg])` the python program would continue execution without waiting for the ./process.sh' to complete?

Comment: No. The `process.sh` will block the parent process. If you want async then you need something like `os.fork()`

Comment: That is correct. `popen` will not block the parent process until you make one of the blocking api calls such as `wait` or `communicate`. `subprocess.run()` and `subprocess.call()`  do block the parent process.

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness: Python's asyncio offers a high level interface for doing just that:
https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#subprocesses

Example from documentation:

```
import asyncio

async def run(cmd):
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
        cmd,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)

    stdout, stderr = await proc.communicate()

    print(f'[{cmd!r} exited with {proc.returncode}]')
    if stdout:
        print(f'[stdout]\n{stdout.decode()}')
    if stderr:
        print(f'[stderr]\n{stderr.decode()}')

asyncio.run(run('ls /zzz'))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fork i.e. `os.fork()` that way you can spawn a child which can outlive the parent process which can be later claimed by `systemd` on Linux. I have no clue about Windows.